# Has many through on a namespaced model

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have the following

```
class Service < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :service_testimonials, class_name: 'Service::Testimonial', dependent: :destroy
  has_many :testimonials, through: :service_testimonials
end

class Service::Testimonial < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :service
  belongs_to :testimonial
end

class Testimonial < ActiveRecord::Base

  has_many :service_testimonials, class_name: 'Service::Testimonial', dependent: :destroy
  has_many :services, through: :service_testimonials
end
```

But if I do `Service.first.testimonials` the sql is `SELECT "service_testimonials".* FROM "service_testimonials" INNER JOIN "service_testimonials" "service_testimonials_testimonials_join" ON "service_testimonials"."id" = "service_testimonials_testimonials_join"."testimonial_id" WHERE "service_testimonials_testimonials_join"."service_id" = $1  [["service_id", 1]]`

So it returns a collection of `Service::Testimonial` not of `Testimonial`, adding `class_name` to the through doesn't help.  Can I get this to work?  Or do I simply need to rename my model?

Comment: When you added `class_name:` (on belongs_to :testimonial presumably) did you use `'::Testimonial'` to ensure you targetted the top level `Testimonial` class?

Comment: @japed I've updated my answer. It's functional now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to make changes in `Service::Testimonial` class:

```
class Service::Testimonial < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :service, class_name: '::Service'
  belongs_to :testimonial, class_name: '::Testimonial'
end
```

Those `class_name`s are obligatory, because Rails [assumes](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#controlling-association-scope), you are looking for a class in the same namespace. So, for instance declaration `belongs_to :service` will be interpreted into `belongs_to :service, class_name: 'Service::Service'`, which obviously is not your intention.

Comment: There is no module `Service`, the class is being used to namespace in `Service::Testimonial` - not saying that *won't* cause problems because it sometimes does (classes and modules load constants slightly differently) but just clarifying there is no module `Service` (at least not in the example given).

Comment: @Shadwell thanks for noting! You are right: there are no `Service` module in this setup. Still I think it should be considered as a bad practice. If we defined `Service::A` class before `Service` class, it would create `Service` module, then `Service` class definition would fail.

Comment: I can see why it might be considered bad practice, my main reason for doing this was to tidy up my models folder.  I think I'm going to unnamespace them and just have it be less organised.  It seems to be causing more problems than it's worth.  Edited your answer as like @Shadwell said I needed to use the top level `Testimonial`.  Thanks for your help